# Padding for anchor tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net, padding

I have a asp.net page with the code as shown below.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
      }
      header,
      footer {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      header li {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0, 153, 255);
        background-color: dodgerblue;
      }
      header li:hover {
        background-color: white;
      }
      header a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      header a:hover {
        color: dodgerblue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <header runat="server">
          <h1>Welcome to SAIC</h1>
          <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Items>
              <asp:MenuItem Value="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Value="Login" NavigateUrl="~/Login.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Value="Add Products" NavigateUrl="~/Add Products.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Value="View Product Details" NavigateUrl="~/View Product Details.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
          </asp:Menu>
        </header>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>Copyrights @ 2016</p>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

I've applied padding for anchor tag. But only `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` are being set. The padding of left and right are not appearing.

I've tried to set `padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;` but that also doesn't work.

Here is the generated source. `/* <![CDATA[ */` is being generated automatically. https://jsfiddle.net/q2Lcrgux/

Comment: I don't see an anchor tag in your code! can you post some fiddle or so?

Comment: Asp.net processes the master page and the menu items are converted into anchor tags. Here is the generated source https://jsfiddle.net/q2Lcrgux/

Comment: ok that works fine for me!

Comment: Yes, it works. I even tried with IE. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Anchor tag is an Inline element. Padding wont work with Inline Element. You have to make it as block element. Making them inline-block must work. http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4d7q6gwp/

```
<a href="#" style="display:block;padding:10px">Click here</a>
```

Style:

```
a
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a{
 display:block;
 padding:15px;
 }//Use This Is inline Element That's Why You Need This Code Try It Once
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

If displaying it as a block or inline-block doesn't work for you, then try putting a `<p>` tag in the anchor tag and add margin or padding to the `<p>` tag:

```html
<a href="https//www.google.com"><p style="margin: 20px;"></p></a>
```